# Sequencing akka router messages

Tags: scala, akka, router

Using akka routers, I have two different operations to be performed. But when I pass the messages, they are overlapped. Here is my code.

```
class Master extends Actor {

    import context._

    val numRoutees = 3
    val router: ActorRef = actorOf (RoundRobinPool (numRoutees).props(Props[Worker]), "router")

    // broadcasts GetString() and receives a random string from each routee
    def stringMessages(replies: Set[String] = Set()): Receive = {
        case GetString() =>
            router ! Broadcast(GetString())     // g
        case reply: String =>
            val updatedReplies = replies + reply
            if (updatedReplies.size == numRoutees) {
                println("result = " + updatedReplies.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
            }
            become(stringMessages(updatedReplies))

        case GetInteger() =>
            become(intMessages())
            //    self ! createArray()  // h      // <- uncommenting this results in an infinte loop

        case _ => println("stringMessages: no matches")
    }

    // broadcasts GetInteger and receives a random integer from each routee
    def intMessages(ints: Set[Int] = Set()): Receive = {
        case GetInteger() =>
            router ! Broadcast(GetInteger())    // e
        case n: Int =>
            val updatedInts = ints + n
            if (updatedInts.size == numRoutees) {
                println("result = " + updatedInts.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
            }
            become(intMessages(updatedInts))

        case GetString() =>
            become(stringMessages())
            self ! GetString()                  // f

        case _ => println("intMessages: no matches")
    }

    override def receive: Receive =
    {
        case GetString() =>
            become(stringMessages())
            self ! GetString()      // c
        case GetInteger() =>
            become(intMessages())
            self ! GetInteger()     // d
        case _ => println("root doesn't match")
    }
}


object MasterTest extends App {
    val system = ActorSystem ("ActorSystem")
    val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Master], "root")

    actor ! GetInteger()        // a
    actor ! GetString()         // b
}
```

With some debug statements I understand the order of execution may be in order `a -> b -> f -> g`. (Note the ids of statements commented in the code). The code doesn't do what I expect it to do. The output is

```
result = [a,b,c]
```

How can I make them execute in the order `a -> d-> e -> b -> f -> g`. If I add a `Thread.sleep` like

```
actor ! GetInteger()        // a
Thread.sleep(3000)
actor ! GetString()         // b
```

I get the expected output, i.e.

```
result = [0,4,6]    // random integers
result = [a,b,c]    // random strings
```

How to make the actor messages queue up in such a way that a new one is executed only after the previous is completely executed. What is a better way to implement what I am doing with `become()`? If I want to add more states in the code (like `GetInteger` and `GetString` here), the code becomes too redundant to change the states using `become(newState)` from one to other.

Also if I uncomment `h` the code turns to an infinite loop with `a -> b -> f -> d -> h -> f -> h -> f -> ...`. So I understand this is not the correct implementation in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to encode both the `String` replies and the `Int` replies in a single `Receive` behavior. For example:

```
case object GetInteger
case object GetString

// ...

def handleMessages(intReplies: Set[Int] = Set(), strReplies: Set[String] = Set()): Receive = {
  case GetInteger =>
    router ! Broadcast(GetInteger)
  case GetString =>
    router ! Broadcast(GetString)
  case i: Int =>
    val updatedInts = intReplies + i
    if (updatedInts.size == numRoutees) {
      println("result = " + updatedInts.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
    }
    become(handleMessages(updatedInts, strReplies))
  case str: String =>
    val updatedStrings = strReplies + str
    if (updatedStrings.size == numRoutees) {
      println("result = " + updatedStrings.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
    }
    become(handleMessages(intReplies, updatedStrings))
  case x =>
    println("Not an Int or String: " + x)
}

def receive = handleMessages
```

Note that I changed `GetInteger` and `GetString` to case objects instead of case classes because they don't have parameters. Doing so allows you to drop the parentheses at the end (i.e., you can use `GetInteger` instead of `GetInteger()`).

Also, if you're concerned about order, consider using an ordered collection such as a `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` instead of a `Set` (which is unordered).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jeffrey. Your answer solves my problem in using `become()`.

But consider having two messages sent as `actor ! GetInteger; actor ! GetInteger`, I receive 6 integers from 3 (`numOfRoutees`) routees. I expect the 3 replies from first message group together (print in first `result = []`) and the 3 from seond message form a group. But I notice that is not always the case. The replies can mix up and the grouping is not always how they are expected to be.

Any solution to fix this?

Comment: Expected: `result = [1$a, 1$b, 1$c]` and `result = [2$a, 2$b, 2$c]`. But get something like: `result = [1$a, 2$a, 1$c]` and `result = [1$b, 2$b, 2$c]`